# jsfiddle: same code different result on same browser

Tags: jsfiddle

> This shows the working jfiddle (Click the color-picker)
>   http://jsfiddle.net/xztoqtd7/

> This shows the non-working jfiddle (Click the color-picker)
>   http://jsfiddle.net/p7dm051z/

They should both change the color of the second row cells, but only one of them does that. Code:

HTML

```
<table>
  <tr>
  <td>
    <input type="color" id="colorpicker1" />
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="color" id="colorpicker2" />
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="one">ipsum</td>
    <td id="two">lorem</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background: #000;
  border-top: 1px solid #777;
  border-left: 1px solid #777;
}

table tr td {
  border-right: 1px solid #777;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #777;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

input {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

JS

```
$("#colorpicker1").on("change", function() {
  $("#one").css("color", $("#colorpicker1").val());
});

$("#colorpicker2").on("change", function() {
  $("#two").css("color", $("#colorpicker2").val());
});
```

Why is the result different?

Comment: basically you did't pick any Jquery library in the not working solution 
your code used Jquery

Comment: @MahmoudZakal Ah, thanks